# DateTimePicker Vb.net empty

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datetimepicker

I am trying to use a DateTimePicker control in Vb.net, but when I run my applications the DateTimePicker is empty. It only shows two diagonals.

Here is the example:

[image: DateTipePicker empty]

I've tried with everything but it is the same. How can I fix this?

[Properties Control DateTimePicker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qhzOY.jpg)

Comment: Please show us how you initialize your DateTimePicker. Maybe also the properties of your control.

Comment: I don't have any instructions in the form, only in the properties, Format:Short, CustomFormat: empty, Cheked: False, Value: 01/01/2016, UseWaitCursor: True, I don´t have any event

Comment: So what should the datepicker initially show? the current date?

Comment: In this case I need to show the date 01/01/2016 and the other 31/12/2016 but only show two diagonals.

Comment: @JASalinas Please update the question with a screenshot of the properties you have set, as well as any code behind relevant to the control (including the designer code in this case I'd say). It might also be worth making note of your Framework version, etc.

Comment: I'm having the same problem.  I tried setting my target framework to the latest, but it made no difference.  I originally let the default value stand, but for debug purposes, I loaded a date into Value.  The Text property was properly formatted, but it showed up in the control as the example above.

Comment: are you using windows 10?

Comment: @ObsidianPhoenix thank you, the screenshot is ready, and yes, I have changed the Framework version, but the result is the same...

Comment: @AlexB.Yes Windows 10 Pro

Comment: It is a wonky computer problem.  The exact way a short date is formatted is a system setting.  Use Control Panel > Language > Change date, time, or number formats > Short date to verify that this setting is still correct.

Comment: There has been some [problems(1)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43397219/datetimepicker-garbled-after-windows-10-creators-update) [problems(2)](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/45389/datetimepicker-control-broken-after-upgrade-to-win.html) with DateTimePickers in the windows 10 creators update

Comment: @HansPassant Just as comment, I'm other applications in the same computer and i don't this problem, my applications works without problems.

Comment: And we are supposed to figure out what is wrong with *this* application from that screen-shot?  Magic could occur, I suppose.

Comment: @HansPassant no of course not, and thank so much for your time.

Comment: @AlexB.Thank you friend this is the answer, Thank you everybodys, so in the Project Propierties select Enable XP Visual Styles, Thank you again.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DateTimePicker garbled after Windows 10 Creators Update](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43397219/datetimepicker-garbled-after-windows-10-creators-update)