# What is the native call equivalent to Application.EnableVisualStyles?

Tags: .net, windows, delphi, delphi-6

I have a legacy windows application that is having screen rendering problems with the latest Win10 Creators update. I see .NET applications can [resolve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43397219/datetimepicker-garbled-after-windows-10-creators-update) the issue by calling [Application.EnableVisualStyles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.enablevisualstyles%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). However given that my app was written pre dotnet (in Delphi 6) I hope there is a native system call that I can use to do the same thing.

Comment: You could always [consult the source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Application.cs,2788587b444f7889).

Comment: Not that simple. If you have a modern enough Delphi it's easy enough. But with Delphi 6 and earlier you need a third party component. So, which version of Delphi do you use.

Comment: Delphi 6. I will update the question to reflect that

Comment: You need to add an application manifest to the project that enables ComCtrl32.dll v6. This is done by default in modern Delphi versions. Delphi has had native support for Windows visual styles since like Delphi 7. In earlier versions, you need to use Soft-Gems' [XP Theme Manager](http://www.soft-gems.net/index.php/controls/windows-xp-theme-manager), which not only provides a manifest but also fixes theming issues with various native Delphi components.

Comment: I'll give it a shot. Write it up as an answer and I'll upvote it. Thank you.

Comment: You should be able to update to D2007 without too much effort. I guess this will fix some issues like the one you're having.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Delphi 6, you cannot use visual styles directly. You need to use a third party library, Mike Lischke's [Windows XP Theme Manager](http://www.soft-gems.net/index.php/controls/windows-xp-theme-manager). In fact this library formed the basis of the built in support that was included in Delphi 7, as can readily be observed by reading the source code.

In order to use this in your Delphi 6 program you need to take the following steps:

1. Include the XP Theme Manager library in your project.
2. Link an application manifest resource to your executable that specifies comctl32 v6. There are many resource online explaining how to do this, I won't repeat them here.

Note that if your program does not currently link an application manifest then you might find that other behaviour changes when you do so. Without a manifest, a program is virtualized under UAC. With a manifest, virtualization is disabled. Now, virtualization was introduced in Vista back in 2005 as a crutch to help developers adapt to changes introduced with UAC. If you still have not adapted your program to UAC, then I would suggest that it is perhaps high time that you do so!

Comment: "need to take the following steps" -> ".. one of the following steps" ?

Comment: @sertac I think you need both

Comment: I probably confused it with the "xpman" unit of D7, which the only thing it does is to include "windowsxp.res".

Comment: @Sertac In D7 step 2 is part of the VCL but it's all Mike's code.